# R: Output text and graphics to pdf

Tags: r, pdf

I'm new to R.
I want to add both descriptive statistics and a histogram to a pdf.

The following code successfully generates two histograms using ggplot2. But the describe (from psych package) functions do not appear in the pdf.
How do I include both?

```
    library(psych)
library(foreign)
library(nnet)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# direct output to a file 
sink("C:\\Users\\jake\\Dropbox\\__iKoda\\datafiles\\OutputR.txt", append=FALSE, split=TRUE)
gc()
memory.limit()


options(max.print=1000000)

results <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\jake\\Dropbox\\__iKoda\\datafiles\\results.csv")



pdf(file="C:\\Users\\jake\\Dropbox\\__iKoda\\datafiles\\plots.pdf")

timesTrimmedComplete=processITStimes(results,"TSICompleted")

print(describe(timesTrimmedComplete$totaltimemins) )

freq=generateQplot(timesTrimmedComplete$totaltimemins,"histogram", 1)
print(freq)




timesTrimmedINComplete=processITStimes(results,"_TSIIncomplete")

print(describe(timesTrimmedINComplete$totaltimemins)) 

freq1=generateQplot(timesTrimmedINComplete$totaltimemins,"histogram", 1)
print(freq1)

dev.off()
########################################################################################

generateQplot<-function(dataVector, plotType, binWidthValue)
{
  freq=qplot(dataVector,geom=plotType, binwidth=binWidthValue)
  return(freq)
}


processITStimes<-function(resultsData, statusCode)
{
  completeResults <- resultsData[grep(statusCode, resultsData$Final_Status), ]
  times <- completeResults[, grep("*duration*", colnames(completeResults))]
  times[is.na(times)] <- 0

  times$totaltime <- rowSums( times[,2:ncol(times)] )
  times$totaltimemins <-round(times$totaltime/60, digits=0)
  times$rowId<-completeResults$RowId
  print(statusCode);
  print(describe(times$totaltimemins) )


  timesTrimmed<-times[times$totaltimemins<60,]

  return(timesTrimmed)

}



sink()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making ggplots, you can always use ggsave(). So you'd do

```
ggsave(plot = freq1, filename = "freq1.pdf", device = "pdf")
```

You can also specify how large to make the plot (height/width/units), etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to include two sets of descriptives and two sets of histograms in one pdf

Comment: Oh I see. If you're trying to make a pdf with multiple objects, your best bet is to create a markdown document and knit it to a pdf. That way you can have your plots, and you can also print from the describe function.
Sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: That's helpful!